# How can I restrict the user from Editing the Account Site Field of account Object using profile settings?

Tags: apex, profile, administration, security, field-level-security

I am facing some issue here regarding field level security in Profile

Sales Admin (Cloned From System Administrator)

- Object Level Security (Standard object permission) Account Object   |  Only Read Access
- Field level security (Standard Field Level Security) Account Site Field  |   Only Read Access
- Administrative Permission Edit Read Only Fields  |  Unchecked
- No permission set Assigned
- Same Page layout assign to System Administration and Sales Admin profile.
- Account page layout --> Account Site --> Read Only | Unchecked

As per above setting user should not be a allow to edit Account site field

But still

Sales Admin Profile Assigned user able to edit the “Account Site” Field.

so how can I restrict the user from Editing the Account Site Field.

Comment: can you check if the profile has "Modify All Data" activated?